# How to update JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

What I want from this program is when pressing on first button, it will display the array assigned and when pressing on the second button is to clear the list and display the array assigned, I've been looking up solution online and many people are suggesting the use of list model, any tips are appreciated.

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class tester extends JFrame{
private JList list = new JList();
private JButton b1 = new JButton("Array1");
private JButton b2 = new JButton("Array2");

public tester(){
    final String [] Array1 = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
    final String [] Array2 = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    p1.add(b1);
    p1.add(b2);
    add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            DefaultListModel Model1 = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
            for(int i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++){
                Model1.addElement(Array1[i]);
            }
        }
    });

    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            DefaultListModel Model2 = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
            for(int i = 0; i < Array2.length; i++){
                Model2.addElement(Array2[i]);
            }
        }
    });

}

public static void main (String [] args){
    tester t1= new tester();
    t1.pack();
    t1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t1.setTitle("Test");
    t1.setVisible(true);
    t1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem you're facing? If you ask a specific question concerning your code, this post would be a perfect candidate for up-votes (and constitute a perfect question), as it already has an MCVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        DefaultListModel Model1 = new DefaultListModel();
        for(int i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++){
            Model1.addElement(Array1[i]);
        }
        list.setModel(Model1);
    }
});

b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        DefaultListModel Model2 = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String Array21 : Array2) {
            Model2.addElement(Array21);
        }
        list.setModel(Model2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a `ClassDCastException` because you're trying to cast `(DefaultListModel)` to a model that is not `DefaultListModel`. You first need to set the model to the list to `DefaultListModel` like this

```
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    list.setModel(model);
```

That will get rid of the `ClassCastException` when you do this

```
    DefaultListModel Model1 = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
```

Also you don't have a button to clear, only to add arrays. So you want a button to clear and in the `actionPerformed` just use

```
    model.removeAllElements();
```

---

Here's a refactored version of your code, that works

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class tester extends JFrame {

    private JList list = new JList();
    private JButton b1 = new JButton("Array1");
    private JButton b2 = new JButton("Array2");
    private JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    private DefaultListModel model;

    public tester() {
        final String[] Array1 = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
        final String[] Array2 = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

        model = new DefaultListModel();
        list.setModel(model);
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        p1.add(b1);
        p1.add(b2);
        p1.add(clear);
        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.removeAllElements();
            }
        });
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultListModel Model1 = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
                for (int i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++) {
                    Model1.addElement(Array1[i]);
                }
            }
        });

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultListModel Model2 = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
                for (int i = 0; i < Array2.length; i++) {
                    Model2.addElement(Array2[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tester t1 = new tester();
        t1.pack();
        t1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        t1.setTitle("Test");
        t1.setVisible(true);
        t1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **here is a sample for you**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Main {
    private static int i = 1;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo Frame/SuRu");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        Container contentPane2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        final JList jList = new JList(model);
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add Element");
        JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove Element");
        JButton removeAllButton = new JButton("Remove All");

        contentPane2.add(addButton);
        contentPane2.add(removeButton);
        contentPane2.add(removeAllButton);
        contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(jList), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(contentPane2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                model.addElement("Element " + i);
                i++;
            }
        });
        removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (jList.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
                    model.remove(jList.getSelectedIndex());
                }
            }
        });
        removeAllButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                model.removeAllElements();
            }
        });

    }
}
```